# Facebook User Level Restriction

Tags: facebook

I am trying to develop a community page on Facebook. Every Facebook page have given some features for restriction which are predefine by Facebook. It contains Country restrictions age restriction etc. Now I want to define manually define restrictions using facebook programming. restriction that I want:

1. my page to be like by specific gender (like only men or only women)
2. restricted gender not be able to see the page content
3. restricted gender cannot be able to comment on any content of the page

I did not see any reference to these type of restrictions on Facebook. If anybody know then guide me through this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no restrictions on gender. I'm pretty sure that this is a discriminating violation in some places... but in anycase, there is no way for you to know what gender the user is before they "like" the page... After that you can see it in the [`signed_request`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/).